# Data export performance issue - loops or joins?

Tags: performance, abap, opensql

I look after a system which uploads flat files generated by ABAP. We have a large file (500,000 records) generated from the HR module in SAP every day which generates a record for every person for the next year. One person gets a record if they are rostered on on a certain day or have planned leave for a given day.

This job takes over 8 hours to run and it is starting to get time critical. I am not an ABAP programmer but I was concerned when discussing this with the programmers as they kept on mentioning 'loops'.

Looking at the source it's just a bunch of single row selects inside nested loops after nested loop. Not only that it has loads of **SELECT**

I suggested to the programmers that they use SQL more heavily but they insist the SAP approved way is to use loops instead of SQL and use the provided SAP functions (i.e to look up the work schedule rule), and that using SQL will be slower.

Being a database programmer I never use loops (cursors) because they are far slower than SQL, and cursors are usually a giveaway that a procedural programmer has been let loose on the database.

I just can't believe that changing an existing program to use SQL more heavily than loops will slow it down. Does anyone have any insight? I can provide more info if needed.

Looking at google, I'm guessing I'll get people from both sides saying it is better.

Comment: I'm inclined to flag this as "primarily opinion-based, but I agree that "8 hours run time" usually means "get someone with an appropriate skill set to take a look at this"

Comment: Since you mention HR, sharing some of the code might be helpful. A question that needs anwsering before any real recommendation can be given is if the SELECTs you mention are in custom code or in SAP function modules?

Comment: This is really an ABAP and SAP question. You need to have someone look at it that is familiar with the APIs SAP provides for this functional area. It is almost certainly being done wrong, resulting in performance problems, but switching to SQL is probably also (but not always) incorrect. See if SAP provides a mass-lookup API.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback everyone. I realise there can be no definitive answer without sample code, but I'm more interested on the feedback on loops vs joins. Having done some more googling, it appears that this is definitely a hot discussion topic.

Answer (score 2):

I've read the question and I stopped when I read this:

> Looking at the source it's just a bunch of single row selects inside
>   nested loops after nested loop. Not only that it has loads of SELECT
>   *.

Without knowing more about the issue this looks overkilling, because with every loop the program executes a call to the database. Maybe this was done in this way because the dataset of the selected data is too big, however it is possible to load chunks of data, then treat them and then repeat the action or you can make a big JOIN and operate over that data. This is a little tricky but trust me that this does the job.

In SAP you must use this kind of techniques when this situations happen. Nothing is more efficient than handling datasets in memory. To this I can recommend the use of sorted and/or hashed tables and BINARY SEARCH.

On the other hand, using a JOIN does not necessarily improves performance, it depends on the knowledge and use of the indexes and foreign keys in the tables. For example, if you join a table to get a description I think is better to load that data in an internal table and get the description from it with a BINARY SEARCH.

I can't tell exactly what is the formula, it depends on the case, Most of the time you have to tweak the code, debug and test and make use of transactions 'ST05' and 'SE30' to check performance and repeat the process. The experience with those issues in SAP gives you a clear sight of these patterns.

My best advice for you is to make a copy of that program and correct it according to your experience. The code that you describe can definitely be improved. What can you loose?

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes - use SE30 (or transaction SAT in newer systems)  there is also a very handy "Tips and Tricks" button that specifically addresses common performance issues.  Among them I believe select *  and select within a loop is addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the import as it stands is looping over single records and importing them into a DB one at a time. It's highly likely that there's a lot of redundancy there. It's a pattern I've seen many times and the general solution we've adopted is to import data in batches...

A SQL Server stored procedure can accept 'table' typed parameters, which on the client/C# side of the database connection are simple lists of some data structure corresponding to the table structure.

A stored procedure can then receive and process multiple rows of your csv file in one call, therefore any joins you need to do are being done on sets of input data which is how relational databases are designed to be used. This is especially beneficial if you're joining out to commonly used data or have lots of foreign keys (which are essentially invoking a join in order to validate the keys you're trying to insert).

We've found that the SQL Server CPU and IO load for a given amount of import data is much reduced by using this approach. It does however require consultation with DBAs and some tuning of indexes to get it to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Without knowing the code, in most cases it is much faster to use views or joins instead of nested loops. (there are exceptions, but they are very rare).

You can define views in SE11 or SE80 and they usually heavily reduce the communication overhead between abap server and database server.

Often there are readily defined views from SAP for common cases.

**edit:**

You can check where your performance goes to: http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/testing-and-troubleshooting/blog/2007/11/13/the-abap-runtime-trace-se30--quick-and-easy

Badly written parts that are used sparsely don't matter.

With the statistics you know where it hurts an where your optimization effort pays.